# How to get all the values inserted in database table from a view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a view in codeigniter. When I give input in one or 2 fields the values are coming from 2 tables in database. I tried a pricing calculation logic in this view where the monthly, weekly, daily rates are coming from a table computers. After the pricing calculation it gives the total rate in one of the field. But all the monthly, weekly and daily rates needs to be inserted in another table. How do I do this?

My controller function:

```
public function pricing()
    {
    $hire_mode = $this->input->post('hire_mode');
    $com_sno = $this->input->post('com_sno');
                $diff = $this->input->post('diff');
                $this->load->model('autocomplete_model');
                $result = $this->autocomplete_model->getRates($com_sno);
                $data = array();
                switch($hire_mode) {
                    case 0:
                        $rate = $result->mohr/30;
                        $total = $diff * $rate;
                        $data['rate'] = $result->mohr;
                        $data['total'] = $total;
                        break;
                case 1:
                    $rate = $result->wehr/7;
                    $total = $diff * $rate;
                    $data['rate'] = $result->mohr;
                    $data['total'] = $total;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $rate = $result->dahr;
                    $total = $diff * $rate;
                    $data['rate'] = $result->mohr;
                    $data['total'] = $total;
                    break;
}
            echo json_encode($data);
}
```

In my view json jquery:

```
    <script>
  $('#diff').change(function () {
    var hireMode = $('input[name=hire_mode]:checked').val();
    var diff = $(this).text();
    var com_sno = $('#com_sno').val();
    console.log(hireMode+'---'+diff+'---'+com_sno)
    $.ajax({ 
           url: "<?php echo base_url();?>autocomplete/pricing", 
           method: "POST", 
           data: {hire_mode:hireMode, com_sno:com_sno, diff:diff}, 
           dataType: 'JSON',
           success: function(res) { 
                $('#rate').val(res.rate);
                $('#total').val(res.total);
                console.log(res);
            } 
    });
  });
```

Comment: In my model:public function add_calendar($array)
 {
      return $this->db->insert('invoice',$array);
 }

Comment: But when i try this insert, only the values in the view gets inserted. But not the monthly, weekly rates which i Have used in the pricing logic

Comment: and where is this insert code? i see no reference to it above. try making it less of a guessing game.

Comment: in my model:<?php
class Calendarmodel extends CI_Model
{

 // get user details
 public function getUserDetails($cus_phone) {
  $this->db->where('cus_phn', $cus_phone);
  $query = $this->db->get('users');
  return $query->row();
 }

 // get computer details
 public function getComputerDetails($comsno) {
  $this->db->where('com_sno', $comsno);
  $query = $this->db->get('computers');
  return $query->row();
 }
 public function add_calendar($array)
 {
      return $this->db->insert('invoice',$array);
 }
}
?>

Comment: Function in my controller where this is getting called:public function add_calendar()
 { if ($this->form_validation->run()){
            $post=$this->input->post();
 unset($post['submit']);
 $this->load->model('calendarmodel','calendar');
 if($this->calendar->add_calendar($post))
 {
  $this->session->set_flashdata('success feedback','Inserted successfully');
  return redirect('invoice');
  //echo "inserted successfully";
 }
 else
 {
  $this->session->set_flashdata('error feedback','Insert failed');
  return redirect('invoice');

}

Comment: Can anyone please give an advice on this?

Comment: I am still waiting for helpful advice on this

Comment: your question still doesn't make sense. and adding comments isn't going to solve it any quicker. revise your question for clarity. when I asked you "where is this insert code?" you posted some code in the comments (which should really be a post edit) that doesn't make sense because in the above code there is no reference to an `add_calendar` function. I would suggest clearing your question and starting from scratch following this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example